# Tmux always shows hostname instead of application running

Tags: zsh, tmux, prezto

A weird thing is happening. I have been trying to debug it for 2 days with no luck. Nothing relevant around forums as well.

I have just set up my wife's machine because I need to work remotely. I have transferred all my set up from my own desktop to my wife's laptop so everything should work just fine. And they do except a small thing which I cannot find out why it's not working. My desktop runs MX Linux 18.3 and my wife's laptop runs MX Linux 19.1

Configuration:

MX Linux 19.1, tmux, zsh, prezto, vim

So the problem now. When I open my terminal under tmux, the status-right shows the hostname. This is all good. When I open VIM though, the status_right pane_title still shows the local hostname while my desktop shows that vim is running plus the full path of the file opened by vim. Same with any other app e.g. htop. My wife's laptop does not update the status-right pane_title while my desktop does. I don't have access to my desktop at the moment so I will only post images of how it looks on my wife's laptop.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using the same versions of `tmux` on both machines? `set-titles` is the relevant option, I think.

Comment: Both machines have tmux-3.0a

Comment: @GeorgeB. What is `status-right` set to?

Comment: @GeorgeB. I think I know what is going on, see if this helps, make sure your `default-terminal` is set to the same value as you have in the `TERM` environment variable before you start your tmux session. For me `TERM` was `xterm` and I've put the following in `tmux.conf`: `set -g default-terminal "xterm"`, after that it changed behavior to what you have described.

Comment: @Zsolt Thank you for your comments status-right is: set -g status-right " \"#{=200:pane_title}\" %H:%M %d-%b-%y" .
echo $TERM -> screen. I added set -g default-terminal "screen" and sourced my .tmux.conf but still nothing. So weird...

Comment: @Zsolt I am getting somewhere. I managed to get it work with XTERM. I set it as you suggested and then after initiating tmux and vim it worked. It isn't working with my gnome terminal. In this use case I have a panel icon which triggers "gnome-terminal -e tmux". With default-terminal set to "screen" it is not working in this case. But really really thank you. Your suggestion gets me half way through

Comment: @GeorgeB. `TERM` should be initialized by the terminal emulator, see this answer here how to do that with GNOME Terminal and set it to `xterm`, I'm guessing you are loading your Default GNOME Terminal profile, so if you change that, that should do the trick: https://askubuntu.com/questions/233280/gnome-terminal-reports-term-to-be-xterm

Comment: @Zsolt Thank you. I managed to make it work both with xterm terminal and xfce terminal but not with gnome terminal. I suppose it might be a bug to this terminal. If you have any other ideas let me know otherwise thank you once more for your help